# Jasmine - TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'win.focus')

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

I'm creating a jasmine test for this line of code :

```
var win = $window.open('url', '_blank', getBrowserSize());
win.focus();
```

and I tried to mock it by this

```
$window: {open: _.noop, focus: _.noop}
```

but when I run the test it gives me this error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'win.focus')
```

Can somebody help me how to mock the focus function on $window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_.noop doesn't have a return value so win is actually undefined.

You might want to try something like this:

```
var $window = {open: function() { return this }, focus: _.noop}
var win = $window.open('url', '_blank', getBrowserSize());
win.focus();
```

Comment: No problems. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

`_.noop` does nothing and returns nothing. So when you do `var win = $window.open('url', '_blank', getBrowserSize());`, `win` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your mock uses `noop` for the `open` method, which returns `undefined` into the `win` variable. Use a function that returns another mock, e.g. as:

```
$window: {
    open: jasmine.createSpy('$window.open'),
    focus: _.noop
}

$window.open.and.returnValue({
    // this is the second mock
    focus: jasmine.createSpy('focus')
});
```